# How to limit filesize in NodeMailer?

Tags: node.js, email, attachment, email-attachments

I'm sending a numerous attached pdf files with nodemailer (if needed I can provide the code).

Now, I need to limit the file size of total sent files to 10 MB, and if it exceeds the 10MB, it should send the next email and continue where it stopped.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the idea, you will write the code. Ask if you need some help later with the code already written.

```
// List all Attachments that must be sent

// For each Attachment, get the size of it using fs.statSync()

// Knowing the number of attachments and the size of each, divide them in groups where the sum of the file size of each group is less than 10MB

// Send one e-mail per group
```